# CSS3 is selecting last child element when it shouldn't

Tags: css

This CSS rule is highlighting the last td element, even though it should not.

```
<tbody>
    {% for thread in object_list %}
    <tr id="unanswered_threads">
            {% load staticfiles %}
            <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.thread_id }}</td>
            <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.subject }}</td>
            <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.latest_post_date }}</td>
            <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.author_username }}</td>
            <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.last_modified_by }}</td>
             <td onclick="gotoLink('{{ thread.url }}');" class="urlLink">{{ thread.assigned_user }}</td>
            <td class="action_button"><a href="/assign_thread/{{ thread.thread_id }}"><img src="{% static 'img/icon_red.gif' %}"></img></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
#unanswered_threads:hover td:not(last-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #2a6496 !important;
}
```

The way this CSS reads, 
 "Selects any td element which is not a first-child element that is a descendant of any element with an id attribute that equals unanswered_threads and which is in a hover state."

Comment: missed a colon, marking a close for error being a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a colon before your `last-child`

```
#unanswered_threads:hover td:not(:last-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #2a6496 !important;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJqUs/1/)

Although it looks like the logic of what you're trying to do is a little odd, you may want to change it to:

```
#unanswered_threads td:not(:last-child):hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #2a6496 !important;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJqUs/)